# MySQL: can not get rid of “Using filesort” in a simple query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Simple query but can not get rid of "using filesort":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `online` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `expiration` (`expiration`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1925234 ;

mysql> explain SELECT i.id, i.uid, i.expiration, u.nick, u.mainpicture
    -> FROM online i join usertable u on i.uid = u.id
    -> order by i.expiration DESC limit 0,12;

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ALL    | uid           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 1020 | Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | dbasen01.i.uid |    1 |                |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`"usertable"` has index on `"id"` column. Tried to order by `"i.id"` (primary key) but the same - query still uses filesort.

Update after RolandoMySQLDBA answer:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |   12 |                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | u               | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | i.uid |    1 |                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | online          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 1009 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
```

**Solution:**

I deleted column "id" because it's not used. Then modified index:

```
ALTER TABLE online ADD INDEX expiration (expiration,uid);
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+----------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | index  | uid           | expiration | 8       | NULL           |   12 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | dbasen01.i.uid |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+----------------+------+-------------+
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: your question was already migrated here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36708/mysql-can-not-get-rid-of-using-filesort

Comment: Can you try adding an index on `(expiration, uid)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to check; however, just looking at the query I expect the filesort is being triggered by the ORDER BY/LIMIT. There isn't much use in doing a sequential O(n) pass over the uid index when it will still have to do O(n) datafile lookups followed by an external sort to extract the first 12 before performing the 12 (or-so) eq_ref joins against usertable's id index followed by probes into usertable's datafile to extract the fields required by select.

I expect Mysql believes (correctly) that it is better to do a single sequential O(n) pass over the datafile followed by the external sort, the eq_ref joins and the probes.

What you need is to do the external sort for mysql up-front, so it doesn't have to do it itself. That means you need a covering index over the join/where conditions.

ie.

```
ALTER TABLE online ADD INDEX expiration (expiration,uid,id);
```

Then again, given there are only 1020 rows in online, why are you worrying about this now?

Comment: Recurse, I accept your answer. First of all I deleted column "id" because it's not used. Then I added ondex on (expiration, uid). That solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT i.id, i.uid, i.expiration, u.nick, u.mainpicture
FROM online i join usertable u on i.uid = u.id
order by i.expiration DESC limit 0,12;
```

Try refactoring the query to coerce the retrieval of 12 rows before doing the JOIN

```
SELECT i.id, i.uid, i.expiration, u.nick, u.mainpicture FROM 
(SELECT * FROM online ORDER BY expiration DESC limit 0,12) i
LEFT JOIN usertable u on i.uid = u.id;
```

The subquery may be forced to use the `expiration` index now.

You can also try this one:

```
SELECT i.id, i.uid, i.expiration, u.nick, u.mainpicture FROM 
(SELECT id FROM online ORDER BY expiration DESC limit 0,12) ik
LEFT JOIN online i on ik.uid = u.id;
LEFT JOIN usertable u on ik.uid = u.id;
```

but you will need redo the expiration index

```
ALTER TABLE online DROP INDEX expiration;
ALTER TABLE online ADD INDEX expiration (expiration,id);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I updated my post with "explain". It still uses filesort.

Comment: I update my answer with another refactored query and an index adjustment.

Comment: @lpalpa "still uses filesort" may be or may not be an issue. Is it faster?

Answer (score -1):

```
explain SELECT i.id, i.uid, i.expiration, u.nick, u.mainpicture, count(*) as bogusvar
-> FROM online i join usertable u on i.uid = u.id
-> GROUP BY i.id
-> order by i.expiration DESC limit 0,12;
```

Adding group by to force the index. Ugly but worked for me.